# How to parse aiml script with an html form?

Tags: html, forms, aiml

Hello i am trying to start with AIML.
using some documentation i got a program which goes like this

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <aiml version="1.0">
> 
> <!-- author: O-Sensei --> <!-- contact: o-sensei@icomsec.net --> <!--
> file: helloworld.aiml -->
> 
> <category> <pattern>*</pattern> <template>Hello World</template>
> </category>
> 
> </aiml>
```

And lot of other examples also But what i want to do  when i am inputting something the aiml script should identify the pattern and it should do the replay. If i am using one form to input the data then how can i invoke the aiml script. Or somthing more like a quick start of AIML. More exactly a use case. I am complete beginner to aiml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some implementation of AIML. [ProgramAB](https://code.google.com/p/program-ab/) is an AIML interpreter written in Java, its open sourced. You need to pass the text input from your form to the chat function defined in the Chat class file.

> chatSession.multisentenceRespond(input)

There are other implementations available for a language of your choice, [ProgramO](http://blog.program-o.com/) is written using PHP and MySQL. Here is a comprehensive [list](http://www.alicebot.org/downloads/programs.html) of some of the freely available interpreters.